# Akka Ask pattern's Timeout blocks code execution

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, akka

I just started to learn Akka library for Scala. I came across using the Ask pattern to get response back from an Actor (just like starting a thread to get some computation done and getting the results out).

Below is my my code where I have used the Ask pattern, in which Timeout blocks it from execution. Why?

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.routing._
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.pattern.ask
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.time.LocalDate
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global 
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}


object Main extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("listRetriever")
  val workerActor = system.actorOf(Props[Worker], "workerActor")
  val listRetriever= new listRetriever
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)

  val future = workerActor ? new Work(date, listRetriever)

  future onComplete {
    case Success(result: Result) => println(result.getList())
    case Failure(result) => println(result)
  }

  system.shutdown
}
```

Comment: You code isn't blocking, at most it's incurring in a timeout because the response from the `workerActor` is never sent back the the asker (as far as one can see). You can't specify an infinite timeout because of the apply method in `Timeout`, you can though specify a ridiculous amount of time (I wouldn't suggest that). Also you may be shutting down the system without having knowledge of wether or not the future is completed.

Comment: Another thing to think about. There is *almost* always a way around using the `ask` pattern. But it requires some thinking. The basic idea is that instead of sending an `ask` use a 'tell` and let the actor respond back to the `sender`.

Comment: I only have a workerActor(just as we start a thread different from the main thread and wait till the result is returned). I want the result to be returned to Main object.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the definition of the `Timeout` class, you'll see that it requires a `FiniteDuration`:

```
case class Timeout(duration: FiniteDuration) extends Product with Serializable
```

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/#akka.util.Timeout

This is intentional so that an `ask` specifically does not run forever.

So no, you cannot use an `ask` without a finite timeout.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning, this is kind of a hack:**
This probably isn't a "best practice", but it is an effective way/workaround to get a no-timeout "ask".

If your original `Work` message was defined like this:

```
case class Work(params: Params)
```

Then add in a `Promise` to that case class, i.e.

```
case class Work(params: Params, completionPromise: Promise[Result])
```

And create a convenience method that deals with creating and sending that message based on the `Params`:

```
def doWork(params: Params): Future[Result] = {
  val completionPromise = Promise[Result]
  val msg = Work(params, completionPromise)
  workerActor ! msg
  completionPromise.future
}
```

This will only work **IF** the `workerActor` implementation knows how to handle the `completionPromise`. If the worker actor implementation isn't under your control, you can't do this.

Also, you **MUST** make sure that the worker actor passes exceptions to the promise. Otherwise, you'll end up with a Future that will never ever complete. For example, this is bad:

```
def receive = {
  case Work(params, completionPromise) =>
    val result = doErrorProneOperation(params)

    // if an exception is thrown, the following will never happen
    completionPromise success result
}
```

You have to make sure to account for exceptions, or else stuff will appear to hang:

```
def receive = {
  case Work(params, completionPromise) =>
    val result = Try { doErrorProneOperation(params) }
    completionPromise complete result
}
```

See [the docs for Promise](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Promise)

Comment: Also won't work if remoting is involved.  Passing futures/promises between actors is a dangerous idea.